# Show HTML5 Notifications without a button to call

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I'm working with HTML5 notifications now, and it's working good when I press the button. But, I want to make it work without a button. Ok, here is the code:

```
<title>(<%= BUSCA2("CHAMADOS") + BUSCA3("TAREFAS")%> - <%= Longa%>) Painel Receptivo - HDTI</title>

<script>

var tempo = '<%= BUSCA2("CHAMADOS") + BUSCA3("TAREFAS")%>';

if(tempo == "0") {

var Notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification || window.webkitNotification;

Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
// console.log(permission);
});

function show() {
var instance = new Notification(
"Chamado Parado", {
body: tempo,
icon: "../logo.png"
}
);

instance.onclick = function () {
// Something to do
};
instance.onerror = function () {
// Something to do
};
instance.onshow = function () {
// Something to do
};
instance.onclose = function () {
// Something to do
};

return false;
}
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="return show()">Notify me!</a>
```

The problem is: as you could see, I get some data from SQL (ASP) and show it in the notification, that's nice. But, I want a IF statement that will only show the notification if 'tempo' is == a zero. Otherwise it will not show anything. How can I make the notification appear without having to click inside of a button? Appear if the 'if' statement was OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the line

```
function show () {
```

and the associated

```
  return false;
}
```

In other words, do not wrap the logic in a function. Then, it will be executed right away when the page is loaded.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much!